# SQL Data Sync with Azure do not show my database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to configure the SQL Data Sync for my Azure SQL Database. So I opened the tutorial from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync).

[image: Azure SQL configuration]

I have selected my Azure SQL Server, but when I want to select my Database theres only the master. And this is the wrong one. I have created another. Anyone knows how to show my database there?

Comment: Did you login with Server Admin?

Comment: Yes, in the step before I logged in with my admin user.

Comment: How many database in your Azure SQL server? if you only have one other database and master db, and you set the other db as the hub database, only the master db you can choose when add member sync database.

Comment: That means I can't use the same database for metadata and my sync data?

Comment: No, you can't.  I will post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have created one database, actually you have two database, master db and other database. That's same with me:

[image]

You can not choose the same database as the member database, only the master db you can choose.
Add member database:
[image]

[SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data) is a service built on Azure SQL Database that lets you synchronize the data you select bi-directionally **across multiple SQL databases and SQL Server instances**.

This means that you can sync the data between the database in same Azure SQL server or other.
[image]

For your question, You want use the same database for metadata and my sync data,
I think you may think about using [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/), Data Factory support you choose the same database  both as source dataset and Sink dataset.

Here's the tutorial: [Copy data to or from Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database).

I think it can help you achieve your purpose.

Hope this helps.